# certain movie frames edit using GPUImage

Tags: iphone, core-image

I want to apply effects on certain frames of movie using GPUImage. I have successfully added effect on entire movie file, so is there a way to add different effects on different frames?

For example, I want to apply effect of Sepia on video from 5 seconds to 10 seconds. So I need 0-5 seconds to be original video, 5-10 seconds with Sepia effect and 10 - video total seconds with original video.

Also, I want to draw text/image on certain frames using GPUImage, is it possible?

Any response will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could ask MPMoviePlayerController or AVAssetImageGenerator to generate a thumbnail at the time you specify.

[iPhone Read UIimage (frames) from video with AVFoundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199879/iphone-read-uiimage-frames-from-video-with-avfoundation)

[AVAssetImageGenerator provides images rotated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347800/avassetimagegenerator-provides-images-rotated)

If you'd like videos instead of just frames, you could trim a section out of the video and apply an effect to that. This takes the URL of your video and trims it to the specified time.

```
    AVURLAsset *videoAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:videoURL options:nil]; 
    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:videoAsset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
    exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputURL];
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    CMTimeRange timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeMake(startMilliseconds, 1000), CMTimeMake(endMilliseconds - startMilliseconds, 1000));
    exportSession.timeRange = timeRange;

    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
        switch (exportSession.status) {
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
                 ///
                // Call something to apply the effect
               ///
                break;
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                NSLog(@"Failed:%@", exportSession.error);
                break;
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
                NSLog(@"Canceled:%@", exportSession.error);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }];
```

Upon completion, you'd then apply your effect and if you went with the video clip route, combine them, and encode them.

[How to combine video clips with different orientation using AVFoundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575128/how-to-combine-video-clips-with-different-orientation-using-avfoundation)

Comment: Brandon, thanks for alternate solution. Do you mean, If I want to apply effect on video from 5 seconds to 10 seconds, I should export this 5 seconds video first and then apply effect using GPUImage and then insert it on original video?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the best solution I can find. I'm certainly not an expert at this, so someone else may have a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I have already thought this one, but I need better solution for this, because It might take time if I apply more than one effects on different different time frames.